# ¿Como podría acomodar esta paginacion?

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap-4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//paginacion que pretendo acomodar

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){

    echo "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm align-items-center'>
    <li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' href='?pagina="."'>"."< Anterior</a></li>

    <li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' style='align-items: right;' href='?pagina=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>

    <li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' href='?pagina="."'>"."Siguiente > </a></li>
    </ul>";
```

Comment: Coloca "anterior" y "siguiente" fuera del bucle for. Crea un Div padre que tenga a los "li" elements con la propiedad display inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
echo "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm align-items-center'>
        <li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' href='?pagina="."'>"."< Anterior</a></li>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++){
    echo "<li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' style='align-items: right;' href='?pagina=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"
}

echo "<li class='page-item align-items-center'><a class='page-link' href='?pagina="."'>"."Siguiente > </a></li></ul>";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudar a ester novato.